# iOS 5.0 view life-cycle issue

Tags: ios, viewwillappear

I'm facing strange behaviour of my custom view controller subclasses on iOS 5.0. I'm not using standart navigation controllers etc. in my iPad application, but I'm presenting all view controllers myself - this is why I needed to call -viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods manually.

Since iOS 5.0, it seems like when adding view controller's view as a subview, these methods are called automatically on view's view controller instance. Which means that these methods are called twice in my case.

Any suggestions? other than creating my own view life-cycle methods and rewriting whole app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your UIViewController to disable the automatic calling of those -viewWill... and -viewDid... methods:

```
-(BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
   return NO;
}
```

This will force iOS 5.0 to stop calling those methods when adding subviews, and won't break anything with iOS 4.x.  I'm using this method as long as I continue to support devices on iOS 4.x.  Once I drop support for iOS 4 I will refactor my code to use the new approach of swapping view controllers (as described in the Session 102 video posted by hypercrypt).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) from WWDC11.

On iOS 5 you need to use proper view controller containment.